# How to apply a 'comma separated list' as a filter in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have a stock-list of books and would like to filter the stock data only with selected publishers.

Is there a way I can provide a 'comma separated list' in the filter?

[image]

I tried the 'Advanced filter' option but it didn't really work. What options do I have?

I am using Excel 2007 and some sample data:

```
ISBN, Title, Publisher, Qty, Price
123213, Title1, Publisher 1, 10, 100
123213, Title1, Publisher 1, 15, 100
143213, Title1, Publisher 3, 16, 10
126213, Title1, Publisher 8, 10, 50
126213, Title1, Publisher 10, 17, 100
```

The advanced filter I tried is:

[image]

Comment: You are nearly there. The advanced filter is exactly the right choice. What Excel version are you using? Maybe you can also edit your question with some sample data. Then we can show you, how to setup the advanced filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How to use *Advanced filter*

1. Setup the criteria range. Make sure, your criteria head and the data table head to filter are exactly the same. In your case: Write `Publisher` instead of `Filter`
2. Place your cursor in your data table. Excel selects the whole data range automatically.
3. Go to *Data* → *Sort & Filter* → *Advanced*
4. Under criteria range: Select the whole criteria range including the header
5. Choose if you want to filter the data in place or copy the result to a new range.
   A single cell is enough.. Excel will expand the range automatically.

[image]
<sup>Apologize for the non-english language dialog. But I guess, you will get the point.</sup>

#### Edit

To avoid the partial match problem that *Publisher 1* will also match *Publisher 10*,
use `="=publisher 1"` instead of `publisher 1` in your criteria range (thx chuff)

Comment: To limit the filter result to include only publisher 1 and not publisher 10, enter the publisher 1 entry in the criteria range as ="=publisher 1". This avoids the default behavior of making a partial match on the criterion.